# What is the quotient of $\mathbb{C}^*$ by the inverse action?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}^*\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}^*$ be the inverse map $z\mapsto z^{-1}$. What is the quotient. I think it is $\mathbb{C}$.

Any point $re^{i\theta}$ is identified with $\frac{1}{r}e^{-i\theta}$. So the complement of the closed unit disc is identified with the interior of the unit disc. Further the upper semi circular portion of the unit circle is mapped to the lower semi circular region. Hence we get a sphere with a puncture, which is $\mathbb{C}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I think this question is asking for the actual quotient, not just something homotopy equivalent.  Also, inversion isn't the antipodal action - it is the identity on $1$ and $-1$, for example.

Comment: @MartianInvader I meant conjugation! Nevermind, anyways.

Comment: What about considering the map $\bf C^*\to \bf C$ $f(z)= z+{1\over z}$

Comment: It’s not a map to $\Bbb C^*$, ’cause $i\mapsto0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks right to me. If you're willing to multiply by $i$, then you can say that the left and right half-circles are identified via $ x + iy \mapsto -x + iy$. You can probably even make the correspondence explicit, via something like this map defined on the unit disk:
$$
r e^{it} \mapsto \frac{r^2 - 1}{r} e^{it}
$$
which takes the interval $[-1, 1]$ (aside from $0$) to the real line, sending both $-1$ and $1$ to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You have a group of order two acting on the (complex projective) line $\Bbb P^1(\Bbb C)$, and you can think of it as $z\mapsto z+\frac1z$. This latter quantity $z+\frac1z$ is a good generator of the fixed field of your two-element group. Under the map $z\mapsto z+\frac1z$, zero and $\infty$ go to $\infty$, and $\pm2$ are the only values $c$ such that the inverse image of $c$ is not a pair of distinct points. That is, the map is ramified only at $1\mapsto2$ and $-1\mapsto-2$.

The upshot is that the quotient is again the complex projective line, or in other language, the Riemann Sphere.

Comment: Nice, John...far more elegant than mine, although it does use a little more machinery. :)

Comment: @Lubin, but the origin is removed right? So isn't the quotient $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Yes, @npna, looking at it from the projective standpoint, the single point $\infty$ in the target space has two points in its inverse image, which were just the points omitted in $\Bbb C^*$. So the image is $\Bbb C$.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that $w + \frac{1}{w} = z + \frac{1}{z}$ if and only if $w = z$ or $w = \frac{1}{z}$, which is why $z \mapsto z + \frac{1}{z}$ maps to the quotient.